# How to integrate a special type of square root function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I am trying to integrate a special type of square root function
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{R^2-x^2}
$$
Where $R$ is constant.
And I want to integrate it with respect to $x$.
$$
    \int_{0}^{R}\sqrt{R^2-x^2} dx
$$
And if I do this:
$$
u = \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\\
x = \sqrt{R^2-u^2}
$$
But this reverses also I don't know any other concept to solve integrals.
Any help will be appreciated.
Note:This is not a homework or exercise question.

Comment: I think the substitution $x/R = \sin(u)$ will work.

Comment: Apart from trigonometric substitution, you can try by parts taking 1 as a constant function and $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ as the other function.

Comment: @Aman Kushwaha could you please elaborate your method.

Comment: @AdityaSingh have you heard of integration method- "By parts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Since $-R \leq x \leq R$, you can make the substitution $x = R\sin(y)$. Then it results that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{R}\sqrt{R^{2} - x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}R\sqrt{R^{2} - R^{2}\sin^{2}(y)}\cos(y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}R^{2}\sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}(y)}\cos(y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}R^{2}\cos^{2}(y)\mathrm{d}y\\\\
& = \frac{R^{2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}[\cos(2y) + 1]\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can solve this and I also understand how you took $x=Rsin(y)$ but can you explain the reason why you made this substitution here.

Comment: I did it mainly because of the range of the argument. You could also choose $x = R\cos(y)$ instead, for example. These substitutions are pretty standard and are presented in any calculus book.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this integral is geometrically.

Note that the integral is the area of a quarter-circle with radius $R$.

Therefore, the integral is $\frac{1}{4} \pi R^2$.

Comment: thank you for your answer and I understood how the integral is area of quarter circle of $R$.

Comment: Glad I could help